# Netbeans: replace a whole block of code on project

Tags: netbeans

I am aware of the **Replace in Project** option on Netbeans, which lets me replace a single line of code at many files simultaneoulsly. But there's a change I need to do on my 25 HTML pages included on the project, changing several classes on the menu, which will be placed on different lines.

Every menu on my HTML files are exactly the same, and by using the default option mentioned I must make every change separately, that makes more than 20 independent changes.

Can I replace blocks of code (not lines) with Netbeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the Match dropdown to Regular Expression, then you can insert '\n' in both the `Find What` field and/or the `Replace With` field to replace a matching block of multiple lines with a block of multiple lines of code.

[image: Replace in projects dialog screenshot with new-lines in both fields]